# Calculate field in modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap, field-calculator, fields-attributes

[image: QuestionCalculateField]

If vb code is also possible I could give that a try aswell.

Comment: Can you try and reword your question? I am having a very hard time trying to decipher what it is you are trying to do here.

Comment: Instead of image, write your question in clear text. It is more searchable and search engine friendly

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry I did not realise it.

Comment: So I would like to reclass a field with the use of two other fields. I am using ArcMap 10.2.1 and would like to use the tool calculate field. All fields are of type string. 
The following is the case: Field 1 and Field 2 are existing/ calculated fields with a value, field 3 is the field I would like to be calculated. Field 1 should be used to update field 2 and give this updated value in field 3. 

So field 1 has unique values from 1-1000. And field 2 has values from 1-3000 of which some are similar.
At the end I would like to have only the values 1-1000 in field 3.

Comment: There is an **edit** button beneath your question that you should use to revise it with the text of your question.  Comments are only temporary.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ModelBuilders' Calculate Field to insert a python code like this:

Expression:

```
calculate(!Field1!, !Field2!)
```

And a code block of:

```
previousValue1 = ""
previousValue2 = ""
previousUnchangedValue1 = ""
def calculate(field1, field2):
 global previousValue1
 global previousValue2
 global previousUnchangedValue1
#First item in list
 if not previousValue1:
    previousValue1 = field1
    previousUnchangedValue1 = field1
    previousValue2 = field2
    return field1
#Current value equals previous value
 if (field2 == previousValue2):
    if previousUnchangedValue1 == previousValue1:
        newValue = previousUnchangedValue1
        previousValue1 = field1
        previousUnchangedValue1 = previousValue1
        previousValue2 = field2
    else:
        newValue = previousUnchangedValue1
        previousValue1 = field1            
        previousValue2 = field2
#Current value doesn't equal previous value
 else:
    if previousUnchangedValue1 == previousValue1:
        newValue = previousValue1
        previousValue1 = field1            
        previousValue2 = field2
    else:
        newValue = previousValue1    
        previousValue1 = field1
        previousUnchangedValue1 = previousValue1
        previousValue2 = field2     
 return newValue
```

The global variable in the python script will hold the previous fields' string value enabling a comparison to the current field value.

There is a lot of if statements in this code, but it will give the desired output.

Comment: @ David Gonzalez. Will this also assign the same values to the values in Field 2 when for example in Field 2 the ObjectID 10 has a value of 'B300' and the ObjectID 236 has a value of 'B300' and I want these values both to be given the same value of Field 1?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to find a cleaner way to solve this problem. My VBScript skills are rusty so I used python instead.

Comment: David, have a look at a dictionary object in python, it will save you a bunch of pain. They are like lists but have a 'key' and a 'value' which can be any type, so for situations where you need to keep 1 = "Rabbit", 2 = "Dog" equality they become *really* handy (or "Rabbit" = 100, "Dog" = 7 for counts with the ability to add new objects at any time).

Comment: Thanks! I've used dictionaries before, but the way I wrote this code, I was just trying to figure out the problem rather than focusing on  structure of the code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way using a [Dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-python) object. To be accessible/updateable for each iteration it must be outside the scope of the function (global) otherwise it's reset for each calculation.

```
preDict = {}
def CalcField3(Field1,Field2):
    global preDict # tell python this isn't a new variable but the other one
    if preDict.has_key(Field2): # if the value has already been encountered
        return preDict[Field2]
    else:
        preDict[Field2] = Field1 # add this key : value pair to the dictionary
        return Field1
```

[image]

Which returns:

[image]

Which isn't quite what you had in your question; the directions and example table provided don't match so I went with the instructions.